# My object has property inside it.but still it gives error 'Cannot read property 'value' of undefined'

Tags: javascript

I am making a card game of war game in Javascript. But having an error of while using Object.value cannot read property of undefined. there is property inside that object. why it is reading undefined?

In this code when player 1 plays card it matches with player 2 card value and whoever has the higher card wins. winner takes both the cards in his hand. the game will continue till one of the player has 52 cards.

this code gives some times winner. but mostly gives an error when one of the player has card more than 45. after that it gives an error is on

> `console.log(`Player 1 plays a ${player1Card.value} of
>   ${player1Card.suit}`);`
>                                                   ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Error is in

> class Game -> turn() method

```js
let draw = false;
let cardOfPlayer1 = [];
let cardOfPlayer2 = [];

class Deck {
  constructor() {
    this.cards = [];
    ["spades","diamonds",'heart','clubs'].forEach(suit => {
      [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14].forEach(value => {
        this.cards.push(new Card(suit, value));
      })
    })
  }

  shuffle() {
    let currentIndex = this.cards.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;
      temporaryValue = this.cards[currentIndex];
      this.cards[currentIndex] = this.cards[randomIndex];
      this.cards[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
  }
}

class Card {
  constructor(suit, value) {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class Player {
  constructor() {
    this.hand = [];
  }
}

class Game {
  constructor(player1, player2, deck) {
    this.players = [player1, player2];
    this.deck = deck;
    this.done = false;
    this.deck.shuffle();
    
  }

  deal() {
    this.deck.cards.forEach((card, index) => {
      this.players[index % 2].hand.push(card);
    });

    console.log(this.players[0].hand, this.players[1].hand);
  }

  play() {
    let count = 0;
    while(!this.done) {
      console.log(`Turn #${count++}`);
      this.turn();
      this.checkWinner();
    }
  }

  turn() {
    const player1Card = this.players[0].hand.shift();
    const player2Card = this.players[1].hand.shift();

    console.log(`Player 1 plays a ${player1Card.value} of ${player1Card.suit}`);
    console.log(`Player 2 plays a ${player2Card.value} of ${player2Card.suit}`);

    if(player1Card.value > player2Card.value) {
      console.log(`Player 1 plays wins this hand`);
      if(!draw){
      this.players[0].hand.push(player1Card);
      this.players[0].hand.push(player2Card);
      }else{
        this.players[0].hand.push(player1Card);
        this.players[0].hand.push(player2Card);
        this.players[0].hand.concat(cardOfPlayer1);
        this.players[0].hand.concat(cardOfPlayer2);
        cardOfPlayer1 = [];
        cardOfPlayer2 = [];
        draw = false;
      }
      console.log(`Player 1 has ${this.players[0].hand.length} cards`);

    } else if(player1Card.value < player2Card.value){
      console.log(`Player 2 plays wins this hand`);
      if(!draw){
        this.players[1].hand.push(player2Card);
        this.players[1].hand.push(player1Card);
        }else{
          this.players[1].hand.push(player2Card);
          this.players[1].hand.push(player1Card);
          this.players[1].hand.concat(cardOfPlayer1);
          this.players[1].hand.concat(cardOfPlayer2);
          cardOfPlayer1 = [];
          cardOfPlayer2 = [];
          draw = false;
        }
      console.log(`Player 2 has ${this.players[1].hand.length} cards`);

    } else if(player1Card.value === player2Card.value){
      
       cardOfPlayer1.push(player1Card);
       cardOfPlayer2.push(player2Card);
      console.log(cardOfPlayer1);
      console.log(cardOfPlayer2);

      draw = true;
      this.turn();

    }
  }

  checkWinner() {
    if (this.players[0].hand.length === this.deck.length) {
      console.log('Player 1 Wins');
      this.done = true;
    } else if (this.players[1].hand.length === this.deck.length) {
      console.log('Player 2 Wins');
      this.done = true;
    }
  }
}

const game = new Game(new Player(), new Player(), new Deck())

game.deal();
game.play();
```

Comment: it gives on the player who has a low card at the end of the game. still, that player has cards still it gives the error.

Comment: yes, but I am not understanding where those cards are vanishing.

Comment: It seems like something wrong with my draw condition, but don't know what

Comment: the cards disappear when a draw is followed by another draw

Comment: Ohh, you were right but I implemented the condition. made cardOfplayer1 an array and pushed the cards in, and then used concat(). with player 1 cards and then emptied the array. I updated the code above can you see why it is still giving the same error.

Comment: I am extremely Sorry about that, I edited before I refreshed the page which has your answer. sorry, my bad. I will change it to the previous one. thank you so much for the help.

Comment: nah, all good :p nothing wrong with having code that doesn't work in a question, I mean, that's why you came here, and somebody else may have an *aha* moment when they realise, *of course, you can have a draw followed by a draw*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only saves 2 cards for a draw - if you have 2 draws in a row, you'll simply lose cards

You also check against this.deck.length, but this.deck is an instance of Deck - you need to check against this.deck.cards.length

I would suggest checkWinner should be

```
  checkWinner() {
    if (this.players[0].hand.length === 0 && this.players[1].hand.length === 0) {
      console.log("It's a draw!!!!!");
    } else if (this.players[0].hand.length === 0) {
      console.log('Player 2 Wins');
      this.done = true;
    } else if (this.players[1].hand.length === 0) {
      console.log('Player 1 Wins');
      this.done = true;
    }
  }
}
```

because if the last hand is a draw, then you will fail to see that there's one player without any cards, so, really, the player wins when the other has no cards left - which is what the above code will do

*You may want to think of some other strategy to your logic for what happens when there is a draw in this case*

There's also the very unlikely but statistically possible circumstance where there are 26 draws in a row - i.e. at some point in the game where both players have 26 cards, then there are 26 draws in a row ... both players will have zero cards left after the last draw ... so, it's a (very unlikely) tie :p

So, the errors corrected below

- do not call this.turn() in the draw condition
- compare each players hand length to 0 to see if the other has won
- if it's a draw, push the current cards to an array
- if it's not a draw, push the array of previously drawn cards from where they are held, then clear those arrays

```js
let draw = false;
let cardOfPlayer1 = [];
let cardOfPlayer2 = [];

class Deck {
  constructor() {
    this.cards = [];
    ["spades", "diamonds", 'heart', 'clubs'].forEach(suit => {
      [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14].forEach(value => {
        this.cards.push(new Card(suit, value));
      })
    })
  }

  shuffle() {
    let currentIndex = this.cards.length,
      temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;
      temporaryValue = this.cards[currentIndex];
      this.cards[currentIndex] = this.cards[randomIndex];
      this.cards[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
  }
}

class Card {
  constructor(suit, value) {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class Player {
  constructor() {
    this.hand = [];
  }
}

class Game {
  constructor(player1, player2, deck) {
    this.players = [player1, player2];
    this.deck = deck;
    this.done = false;
    this.deck.shuffle();

  }

  deal() {
    this.deck.cards.forEach((card, index) => {
      this.players[index % 2].hand.push(card);
    });

    //console.log(this.players[0].hand, this.players[1].hand);
  }
  play() {
    let count = 0;
    while (!this.done) {
      console.log(`Turn #${count++}`);
      this.turn();
      this.checkWinner();
    }
  }

  turn() {
    const player1Card = this.players[0].hand.shift();
    const player2Card = this.players[1].hand.shift();

    console.log(`Player 1 plays a ${player1Card.value} of ${player1Card.suit}`);
    console.log(`Player 2 plays a ${player2Card.value} of ${player2Card.suit}`);

    if (player1Card.value > player2Card.value) {
      console.log(`Player 1 plays wins this hand`);
      if (!draw) {
        this.players[0].hand.push(player1Card);
        this.players[0].hand.push(player2Card);
      } else {
        this.players[0].hand.push(player1Card);
        this.players[0].hand.push(player2Card);
        this.players[0].hand.push(...cardOfPlayer1.splice(0,26));
        this.players[0].hand.push(...cardOfPlayer2.splice(0,26));
        draw = false;
      }
      console.log(`Player 1 has ${this.players[0].hand.length} cards`);

    } else if (player1Card.value < player2Card.value) {
      console.log(`Player 2 plays wins this hand`);
      if (!draw) {
        this.players[1].hand.push(player2Card);
        this.players[1].hand.push(player1Card);
      } else {
        this.players[1].hand.push(player2Card);
        this.players[1].hand.push(player1Card);
        this.players[1].hand.push(...cardOfPlayer1.splice(0,26));
        this.players[1].hand.push(...cardOfPlayer2.splice(0,26));
        draw = false;
      }
      console.log(`Player 2 has ${this.players[1].hand.length} cards`);

    } else if (player1Card.value === player2Card.value) {
      console.log('Draw');
      cardOfPlayer1.push(player1Card);
      cardOfPlayer2.push(player2Card);
      draw = true;
      //this.turn();

    }
  }

  checkWinner() {
    if (this.players[0].hand.length === 0 && this.players[1].hand.length === 0) {
      console.log("It's a draw!!!!!");
    } else if (this.players[0].hand.length === 0) {
      console.log('Player 2 Wins');
      this.done = true;
    } else if (this.players[1].hand.length === 0) {
      console.log('Player 1 Wins');
      this.done = true;
    }
  }
}

const game = new Game(new Player(), new Player(), new Deck())

game.deal();
game.play();
```

Answer (score -1):

This happens because `shift()` removes the first item of an array.

Comment: Ya, that's why I used it. but still, that player has cards as property. this error should come after if any player has 52 cards on him and the other one has zero cards. but this error comes on when one player has 44-48 cards and other has 8-4 cards remaining.

Comment: `but this error comes on when one player has 44-48 cards and other has 8-4 cards remaining` you're assuming what the other player has - since you only ever show how many cards the player with the winning hand has - @AbhijeetBrahmbhatt - and as I've shown you, the cards are disappearing when you have 2 or more draws in a row